# What is a default limit of Firestore query?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have a collection `mycollection` that has 1,000,000 records.

How many records will this query return?

```js
const query = firestore.collection('mycollection').get()
```

I couldn't find that in docs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no default limit.  The query you're showing is asking for all of the documents in `mycollection`.  For large collections, you will need to impose a limit in order to avoid excessive costs and running out of memory.

From [firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) documentation:

> By default, a query retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in
>   ascending order by document ID. You can specify the sort order for
>   your data using orderBy(), and you can limit the number of documents
>   retrieved using limit().

Comment: Thanks. So in the case above the app would try to fetch 1,000,000 of documents?

Comment: The client is requesting every document in the collection.  If the document contains 1 million documents, then the client is going to receive 1 million documents.

Comment: You mean it is requesting *all* the documents? Not one by one, right?

Comment: That's how queries work, yes.  You will receive a QuerySnapshot object that contains the entire result set.  If you want partial results and iterate through them without receiving the entire set at once, you should consider reading about pagination.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors